# android internal socket connection fails with a daemon service

Tags: android, c, sockets, daemon, gstreamer

I've gstreamer decoder application written in 'C' which decodes a h264 frame in Android. I want my camera service to communicate with this application. For this, I've used sockets (dgram). Am creating an unix PF_INET socket with path "/data/cam_file".

Now the issue is, if I run the gstreamer application from command line (adb shell), am able to connect to it from camera service and exchange data, but if I make the gstreamer application as daemon service (with late_start option), the socket connection fails. It also fails if I fork the gstreamer application using processbuilder() from camera app source. Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is solved. The issue was with the permissions of native service. I set the user as 'root' due to which other services are not able to connect to it in the init..rc. If we set the user as 'system' then other services are able to connect. Remember to add 'system' in 'group' settings of the service which is connecting the native service. Hope it will help any beginners.